# C# wont open connection

Tags: c#, mysql

I have created a system that connects to the server to retrieve data from the Database, however I get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll"...

Everything is fine if I connect to the localhost....

```
    string StrCon = string.Format("Server= Cant tell you ; database={0};UID= cant tell you ; password='cant tell you '", "cant tell you");
        MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection(StrCon);

        while (true)
        {
            //MySqlConnection Connection = null;
            Console.WriteLine("not connected");
            Connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("connected");
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM lat_long WHERE ID=1";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, Connection);
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Is the port to the remote server open? First try to disable firewall. If it works, reenable it and add firewall exeption (most common issue in my experience)

Comment: wrap your code around a `try{]catch(SqlException sqlex){}` and tell us what the actual error is.. also put the connection string in a .config file and read it from there..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the firewall on the host is not opened and/or the mysql server is bound to 0.0.0.0 or the interface adress - if it's bound to 127.0.0.1/::1 the server won't be reachable via network.

Comment: use netstat and check on which adresses port 3306 (if default port) is bound and/or use telnet/putty and check if this port is reachable from network. if port is bound to the interface address (maybe something like 192.168.1.1) but not reachable from the network, check the windows firewall if the port is allowed.

Comment: I am using godaddy and I've added my IP to the remote SQL but I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: can you establish a tcp connection (via telnet or anything else) with the server on port 3306?